# Nestjs Repository test fails with error "Received promise resolved instead of rejected"

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, nestjs

I am writing unit tests for my backend application, I am struggling to test for a item in the database not being found, this is the code for my repository to be tested:

```
@EntityRepository(Collectible)
export class CollectibleRepository extends Repository<Collectible> {
  async getCollectible(id: number) {
    const collectible = await this.findOne(id);
    if (!collectible) {
      throw new NotFoundException();
    }
    return collectible;
  }
}
```

And this is the code for testing, I will only show this test case.

```
const mockCollectible = new Collectible(
  faker.lorem.sentence(),
  faker.lorem.sentences(3),
  faker.datatype.float(),
  faker.datatype.float(),
  faker.datatype.number(),
);

describe('Collectible Repository', () => {
  let collectibleRepository: CollectibleRepository;

  beforeEach(async () => {
    const module = await Test.createTestingModule({
      providers: [CollectibleRepository],
    }).compile();

    collectibleRepository = module.get<CollectibleRepository>(
      CollectibleRepository,
    );
  });

  describe('View Collectibles', () => {
       it('throws and error as the collectible is not found', async (done) => {
      collectibleRepository.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined);
      await expect(collectibleRepository.getCollectible(1)).rejects.toThrow(
        NotFoundException,
      );
      done();
    });
  });
});
```

This causes the following error output:

```
Expected message: not "Not Found"

       8 |     const collectible = await this.findOne(id, { relations: ['business'] });
       9 |     if (!collectible) {
    > 10 |       throw new NotFoundException();
         |             ^
      11 |     }
      12 |     return collectible;
      13 |   }

      at CollectibleRepository.getCollectibleBusiness (src/collectible/collectible.repository.ts:10:13)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:95012) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 3)
(node:95012) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
 FAIL  src/collectible/collectible.repository.spec.ts (8.525 s)
  ● Collectible Repository › View Collectibles › throws and error as the collectible is not found

    expect(received).rejects.not.toThrow()

    Received promise resolved instead of rejected
    Resolved to value: undefined

      39 |     it('throws and error as the collectible is not found', async (done) => {
      40 |       collectibleRepository.findOne = jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(undefined);
    > 41 |       await expect(collectibleRepository.getCollectible(1)).rejects.not.toThrow(
         |             ^
      42 |         NotFoundException,
      43 |       );
      44 |       done();

      at expect (../node_modules/expect/build/index.js:134:15)
      at Object.<anonymous> (collectible/collectible.repository.spec.ts:41:13)
```

I tried using [this repository](https://github.com/jmcdo29/testing-nestjs/tree/master/apps/typeorm-sample) (which was mentioned in another SO thread) with a set of examples for testing Nest.js applications, but it seems like a repository is not being directly tested.

**Update:** I updated my code since I was missing a `await` in my code (as noted by [Micael Levi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5290447/micael-levi) ), I was also calling the wrong function (lol). I am receiving the following *warning*:

```
(node:98378) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).rejects.not.toThrow(expected)
```

Though probably I will ignore it unless it affects my CI pipeline (which I need to configure lmao)

**Update 2:** Warning was caused by another test (I may rest for now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you missed the `await` in `const collectible = this.findOne(id);`

So

`const collectible = await this.findOne(id);`

Comment: It looks like this was a cause, I also noticed a typo on my part. The test does pass though I get a warning for `(node:98378) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: expect(received).rejects.not.toThrow(expected)`